# Apply attributes to custom nested element in an angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

I am currently building one of my first custom HTML Element with an AngularJS directive. I want to customize the range input type from HTML5. So far so good, my first steps was made of success. But now I want to enhance the current state with a nested template. At the moment I have sth. like this:

```
.directive("mySlider", [function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            min: "@",
            max: "@",
            step: "@?",
            ngModel: "="
        },
        template: "<input class='my-slider' type='range'>",
        link: function ($scope, $element) {

            //some logic here
        }
    }
}]);
```

With that, if I use

`<my-slider min="0" max="10" step="1" ng-model="sth"></my-slider>`

I get a replacement like so:

`<input class="my-slider" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" ng-model="sth">`

Thats nice as the attributes from scope are written to the input type and can then be used directly.

But here is my problem: Now I want some output HTML like:

`<div>`

`<label>blah</label>`

`<input class="my-slider" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" ng-model="sth">`

`</div>`

So my input element should be nested into a div, maybe with additional element like a label or sth. But when I update my template and just go around nesting my input there, all the attributes from the directive scope are applied to the root element (the div in this case). I don't want them there but on the input element.

Is it possible and how can I achieve to apply certain attributes from the directives scope to different specific elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ngModel: "="` to `sth: "=ngModel"` to get the input model working. Use {{}} notation as you pointed out in the comments here for the attributes. And then make your parent attributes something like `data-min` so you don't have ugly source code.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. Seems to me that I'm just copying the attributes from the root element to the nested one? But I want to apply them ONLY to the the input and remove them from the parent div. Beside that it looks like I can't access the ng-model from my-slider on the input.

Comment: Because you have nothing in your scope named "sth", if you want that to work you need to change your isolate to `sth: '=ngModel'` which will give you a scope variable sth bi-directionally bound to the ng-model of the directive.

Comment: The `var $input` bit applies it ONLY to the input. If you want them removed from the parent then you lose the flexibility of the directive. It shouldn't matter since a "min" on a div doesn't do anything anyway. If you want you can prefix with `data-min` to make it less ugly. Data prefix is ignored by angular I think so the internal code doesn't change.

Comment: Hm, you are right about the data-attributes. I just saw this thread and it looks like it could solve my problem. Looks way cleaner to me. I didn't know I could link the scope variables to any element by {{}}: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15920467/2577116

Comment: Oh yea, that's way simpler. Do it that way, edited my answer.